# How to merge 2 accounts with same email address after merge of 2 woocommerce databases

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, mysql

I need to merge Woocommerce customers accounts with same emails for each one.
I've merged two Woocommerce databases - there are few customers on each of them.

My question is how to merge with accounts in the database and save information of old id to change it in orders, points, etc.?

Comment: How did you merge the 2 databases together?

Comment: In each table of the second DB, I did change ids etc by increasing it by some number, then I exported each table into separate files and import into first DB.

Comment: Are WooCommerce customer accounts default WordPress user accounts (regarding DB)?

Comment: Did you successfully update the user IDs on all the other tables that got migrated over? Also, +1 to kaisers question, if this is going to require WooCommerce specific knowledge to answer, then it would be offtopic on this site

Comment: @kaiser yes, there are

Comment: @KonradSiczek Then you might want to cut WooCommerce (off topic) out here with an [edit] and maybe explain a bit more verbose what you tried, how you tried it and where you are stuck. The question already got pending close votes.